# iFrame Security Risks from Embedding by Hacker

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, clickjacking

Within my app (http://www.example.com) I am running an iFrame (https://www.example.com/iframe-application).

The main page (www.example.com) only renders custom data based on cookies set by the iFrame.  The iFrame has all the smarts, the Javascript, the secure cookies, etc.  The iFrame has NO text, images, etc. only javascript code.

Is there any risk that someone would embed the iFrame in another site and access secure cookies, login tokens, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default cookies are bound to the domain name, so in normal case that should not possible.

If you got a XSS Vuln. on your site, he could access the cookies, so rather be sure to escape all Inputstrings.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a cross-site scripting attack and most browser will prevent it unless the user has configured them not to.

Comment: It would be a XSS Vuln. if the site got the possibility to include User Content, so that he can load JS which sends the Cookie Data to a custom Script which saves it. 

The case asked by the User is no XSS Problem by default.

Comment: The iFrame will NOT have any user inputs, but the Parent WILL have user input.  So, would you say there is a risk only to the parent page, but the iFrame is secure even if an attacker placed the iFrame in another page (ie. evil.com placed https://www.example.com/iframe-application in an iFrame.  evil.com would NOT have access to cookies nor XSS correct?)

Comment: Correct, like written in my answer.